# Matlab oop, non-static functions: Input-argument tooltip issues

Tags: matlab, oop, methods, tooltip

Consider the following class definition:

```
classdef myClass
    properties
        propX
    end    
    methods (Static = false)
        function self = myFunNonStatic(self,arg1,arg2)
            self.propX = doSomething(arg1,arg2);
        end
    end
    methods (Static = true)
        function x = myFunStatic(arg1,arg2)
            x = doSomething(arg1,arg2);            
        end
    end
end
```

Like any standalone function, there will be a helpful tooltip that refers to the input arguments when the static-function call is typed:

[image: Static-function call]

However, the non-static-function call will only provide a useless tooltip that refers to the obvious first argument and nothing else:

[image: Non-static-function call]

I would want to to have the tooltip say `myFunNonStatic(arg1,arg2)` or `myFunNonStatic(myClass object,arg1,arg2)`. I do a lot of oop in Matlab lately and this is bugging me a lot because I always need to open the function's code-block to look up the input arguments of non-static functions.

Also, the tooltip for the call of a static function from a class instance fails to give any information:

[image: Static-function call from class instance]

Does anyone know how these issues can be dealt with?
I read about the `functionSignatures.json` definitions [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/306157-how-to-configure-tab-completion-for-my-function-in-matlab-2016#answer_237857), but this seems to work only with standalone functions but not classes and their functions. Or am I missing something?